# reference textbox within class module

Tags: vba, excel

In my userform I have a constant textbox and then the rest of the controls on the form are dynamic, the dynamic controls are created during run-time and are all handled within a class module. However, is there a way I can reference my my constant textbox `textbox1` whenever I am  in the class module because it doesn't seem to even recognize the name of the textbox when I type it in?

Comment: You could also add another textbox variable to the class and assign the form textbox to that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as:

```
[CLASS/FORM].textbox1
```

to reference the textbox

Comment: this answer is perfect, my confusion is because I didn't think that I would have to reference the form when the class is already associated with it and thats why this simple solution slipped my mind. But thanks very much for the answer